# Getting a pointer to a value result from a function

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm working with a framework that delivers and sets vertex positions only through function calls. For instance

```
Point3 pos = mesh->GetVert(0);
mesh->SetVert(0, pos);
```

Now I'm trying to optimize an algorithm that requires me to loop through all the vertices and also keep the last vertex in mind so I tried this:

```
Point3* current, last;
current = &mesh->GetVert(0);
for (int i = 1; i < mesh->VertCount(); i++) {
    last = current;
    current = &mesh->GetVert(i);

    do stuff...
}
```

but what I found out was that the pointer current gets set to something like 0x12003 every single time and never actually points to the Point3 data. I was under the impression that what I tried to do was possible? After all, when dealing with the same frameworks worldspaces(glorified matrices), adding & in front of the querying function call successfully returns a pointer to the worldspace object.

Confused now, what gives?

Comment: What is the function signature for GetVert()?

Comment: Likely, you are taking the address of a temporary

Comment: CoreExport Point3 GetVert(int i); CoreExport is a dllimport/export macro

Comment: Dieter Lücking: derp, guess there is nothing I can do about that.

Comment: How are you even compiling it? gcc 4.9.2 gives me an error on this: `error: taking address of temporary [-fpermissive]`. Additionally, this line: `last = current;`  gives another one: `error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘Point3’ and ‘Point3*’)`, which is quite correct (as `Point3* current, last;` means `Point3* current; Point3 last;`).

Comment: it was a typo on explaining the problem, supposed to be *last on first line. otherwise it compiles fine on vc++11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code:

```
current = &mesh->GetVert(0);
```

can perhaps be more illustratively thought of as:

```
{
    Point3 _tmp_point = mesh->GetVert(0);
    current = &_tmp_point;
    // _tmp_point gets destroyed
}
// current points to destroyed temporary
```

(Note: I'm assuming that `GetVert` returns a `Point3` and not a `Point3&`, otherwise you wouldn't be having any problems)

Basically the problem is that `current` points to a temporary `Point3` that gets the destroyed at the end of the assignment statement. The code as written guarantees that you have a dangling pointer!

The simple solution is just to note use pointers:

```
for (int i = 1; i < mesh->VertCount(); i++) {
    Point3 current = mesh->GetVert(i);
    // etc.
```

Note that due to the [Return Value Optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization), `GetVert()` will likely construct its returned object in-place in `current` - so this will be efficient.

Comment: It will be efficient in the sense that there is no copy of  the `Point3` from `GetVert``to `current`. But there is a construction anyway, which is extremely infefficient in this case. Am I wrong?

Comment: @JaviV Given the choice between code that definitely works and code that definitely doesn't work, I'll take the functional code every time. The only way to avoid any extra constructions is to have `GetVert()` return a `Point3&` or `Point3*`.